# Use knockout handler to resize div and slide in other div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, knockout.js

I have fullcalendar.js wrapped in a div (**content**) (I use bootstrap3 to set the size).

This **content** area of the page is currently setup to cover only 2/3rds of the left side of the page and the other 1/3rd of the page on the right side, is blank.

The right side remains blank/empty until a button is clicked and then ko will slide in a side form (id="*sideform*") to take up the empty space.

What I need to do is instead of starting with a page split 70%/30% where the 30% is blank, I would like the **content** area to actually start at 100%/0%.

Then if a *sideform* is in place, I want to **content** area re-size from the 100%/0% to the  70%/30% of the page, else 100%/0%.

Since there are a lot of pages like this and after watching John Papa's videos, I believe creating a handler would be the best way to go.

For the last couple of weeks I have looked at and tried to modify examples to do what I need, but with no luck.

The **contents** col-md-9 and col-lg-9 represent 70% of the screen width and *sideforms* col-md-3 and col-lg-3 represents the other 1/3 of the page.

The page is currently setup like...

```
 <div class="container">
     <div id="**content**" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9">
         <div class="calendar" data-bind="fullCalendar: {}"></div>
     </div>    
     <div id="*sideform*" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 pull-right">
         <!--ko router: { transition:'entrance', cacheViews:false,activate: true }-->
         <!--/ko-->
     </div>

 </div>
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add an observable, `sideFormShowing`, to the appropriate section of your ViewModel, and initialize it to false.

Second, add `data-bind="if: sideFormShowing"` to the `*sideform*` div (BTW, I don't think asterisks are allowed as leading characters, if it all, in HTML ids).

Third, take `col-md-9 col-lg-9` out of the `class` attribute on your `**content**` div, and add the following binding to it:

```
data-bind="css: {'col-md-9 col-lg-9': sideFormShowing,
  'col-md-12 col-lg-12': !sideFormShowing()}"
```

Don't forget the quotes around the class-name lists and the parens in the second entry.

Now whenever `sideFormShowing` is false the content div will take up 100% and the sideform div won't be rendered; when it's true the content will shrink to 70% and the sideform will be rendered (I used an `if` binding rather than `visible` because you presumably don't want the virtual-element bindings to run unless the sideform should be shown.